# Creating an iPhone Application in Xcode 4.1.1 - Program received signal "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I'm new to creating iPhone Applications and have just started with Xcode and am getting the following errors; I have used this code previously on both the simulator & an iPod touch and it worked fine for both but for some reason lately it will not allow me to go from one page to another without giving me the "SIGABRT" error.

Basically in my application I need to go from one page to another several times but it will not work....can anyone help with this please?

This is the code it seems unhappy with (it complies & builds successfully):

```
1  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
2
3  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
4  {
5    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
6    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
7    [pool release];
8    return retVal;
9  }
```

It stops on the *int retVal* line (*6th line*).

When debugging it gave the error:

2011-09-09 15:33:59.029 TruckFile[1072:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< UIApplication 0x6044600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'

Can anyone help me with this please?

### Thank you in advance!

========================================

Code files:

========================================

## Main page (.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewTwoController.h"
#import "TruckFileAppDelegate.h"


@interface TruckFileAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
        ViewTwoController *viewTwoContoller; 
        UINavigationController *navigationController;
}



@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator     *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewTwoController *viewTwoController;

-(IBAction)switchPage:(id)sender;


@end
```

================================================

## Main page (.m)

```
#import "TruckFileAppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewTwoController.h"

@implementation TruckFileAppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize viewTwoController;

-(IBAction)switchPage:(id)sender
{
if(self.viewTwoController == nil)
{
    ViewTwoController *viewTwo = [[ViewTwoController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"ViewTwoController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.viewTwoController = viewTwo;
    [viewTwo release];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewTwoController animated:YES];
}


 - (void)dealloc {
[navigationController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

====================================

## Page 2 (.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


 @interface ViewTwoController : UIViewController {

}

@end
```

=====================================

## Page 2 (.m)

```
#import "ViewTwoController.h"


    @implementation ViewTwoController


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
    }


    - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    }


    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mainWindow.xib is trying to connect it's UIWindow instance with your UIApplicationDelegate's and it can't find it (that's why it complains it can't set the value for an UNDEFINED key).

Check your UIApplicationDelegate class has a UIWindow iVar, a property in its .h and it's correctly synthesized in its .m.

**EDIT**

Who's calling the method `switchPage:` on `UIApplication`? If you are, you're calling it on the wrong object. Instead of doing

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] switchPage:xxx];
```

You should do:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] switchPage:xxx];
```

Since the method `switchPage:` is defined in the `UIApplicationDelegate` class.

Comment: Ive checked both files and the UIWindow seems ok....? 
In the .h file: 

'#import "TruckFileAppDelegate.h"


@ interface TruckFileAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
            UIWindow *window;
            ViewTwoController *viewTwoContoller; 
            UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@ property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;' 

In the .m file:
'@ synthesize window;'

Thanks =], I'm a bit confused now...i've tried a lot of different things but am quite stuck. All i want is one page to go to another / it to run on an iPod touch / iPhone.

Comment: Mmmmm... definitely that exception is because you have a IBOutlet connection in one of your .xibs that points to something that doesn't exist in the controller. Check all of your .xib files in the connections tab for something with a (!).

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think it may be because there's a missing connection! Check the MainWindow.xib has the object Window at the left connected to the window IBOutlet of the appDelegate

Comment: Thankyou for your help but it still doesn't seem to work.... :( I've tried the connections & they are all connected.

Comment: Can you confirm that fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails at

```
 [UIApplication switchPage:]:
```

Comment: ok but do you know why it is failing please? Do you need to see samples of further code?

Comment: more code please, especially the segment of  [UIApplication switchPage:]:

Comment: I'm trying to add more code but it will not allow me to format it correctly :S. I'll add it to the main question.

Comment: is you nib file named ViewTwo.xib oder ViewTwoController.xib?

Comment: ViewTwoController.xib is the second page i'm trying to go too. I have two pages; MainWindow_iPhone.xib with TruckFileAppDelegate.h & .m and then ViewTwoController.xib & .m & .h    I'm trying to go from the main page to the ViewTwo page. Thanks for your help, i appreciate it!

Comment: You are using the wrong nib name :)this should work:    ViewTwoController *viewTwo = [[ViewTwoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewTwoController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: Thankyou for your help! =] it built without errors but won't launch anymore....it gave me the same SIGABRT message stating: "2011-09-09 14:27:08.440 TruckFile[124:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x119190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'"

Answer (score 0):

```
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication switchPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600beb0'
```

This means that in your switchPage method, you are giving an action to an unknown identifier, maybe check the object identifier name, and check if you have initialized it in your .h file.

Comment: I've initialised my .h file but it has a yellow warning saying "incomplete implementation of class" but it is compiling & building fine and saying build succeeded. I followed Jussi's comments above by renaming my nib but it now won't launch, it just displays a black screen on the iPod Touch, displays the SIGABRT on the same line & in debugging displays "2011-09-09 14:27:08.440 TruckFile[124:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x119190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'"